# How to check if value is 10 or more minutes from now?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to check if value is 10 or more mins from now.

```
let now = new Date().getTime();
let TEN_MINUTES = new Date().getTime() + 600000;

let val = '2022-01-14 12:27:05+00:00'


if(val > TEN_MINUTES){
   console.log('true')
}
```

Comment: `if (value - now >= 600000) { /* do smth */ }`

Comment: What is `val`? A boolean? If not, why compare it to a boolean? Also note that the first three lines of code as shown are equivalent to `let tenMinsPlus = true;` since you **know** that `TEN_MINUTES > now` is true, since you literally just created `now` and `TEN_MINUTES`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just edited the question and add what comes the val, please check

Answer (score 2):

`val` is a non-blank string, so `val > tenMinsPlus` doesn't make any sense, since `tenMinsPlus` is a boolean.

If you want to know whether `val` is more than ten minutes from now, you need to get a date-like value for `val` and a date-like value for ten minutes from now, and compare them.

You're getting `TEN_MINUTES` correctly:

```
let TEN_MINUTES = new Date().getTime() + 600000;
```

although you can do that more concisely:

```
let TEN_MINUTES = Date.now() + 600000;
```

Both of those give us a number of milliseconds since The Epoch (Jan 1st 1970 at midnight UTC) for "now" plus ten minutes.

Now let's do the date. Your string is *almost* in [a valid format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date-time-string-format) for the `Date` object to parse. It just needs the space after the date changed into a `T`, then we can use `Date.parse` to parse it and give us the number of milliseconds since The Epoch:

```
let then = Date.parse(val.replace(" ", "T"));
```

Then we see whether `then` is greater than `TEN_MINUTES`:

```
if (then > TEN_MINUTES) {
    // Yes, it's more than ten minutes from now
} else {
    // No, it isn't
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function moreThan10Minutes(val) {
    let TEN_MINUTES = Date.now() + 600000;
    let then = Date.parse(val.replace(" ", "T"));
    return then > TEN_MINUTES;
}
function test(val) {
    const result = moreThan10Minutes(val);
    if (result) {
        console.log(`Yes, ${val} is more than 10 minutes from now`);
    } else {
        console.log(`No, ${val} is not more than 10 minutes from now`);
    }
}

test("2022-01-14 12:27:05+00:00");
test(new Date(Date.now() + 700000).toISOString());
```